# Python speech recognition: speech contexts, phrases, config

Tags: python, speech-recognition

I have audio files that contain only numbers. I want to improve the accuracy of the script by listening out specifically for numbers.

Initially, the output of the script was "35y 6883", which is incorrect. The narrator actually said "5", but the system heard "y" because it had not been configured to listen out for numbers specifically.

Here is my code: I am unable to add the config correctly. Help sincerely appreciated.

```
import speech_recognition as sr
filename = "numbers.wav"

"config": {
    "speechContexts": [{
      "phrases": ["one", "two", "three", "four"]
    }]
}

r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.AudioFile(filename) as source:
    audio_data = r.record(source)
    text = r.recognize_google(audio_data, config)
    print(text)
```

Comment: I am also facing same problem is there any way to use the `config` like in google-speech-api